# What is object ID -710746692?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using SentryOne, and have what I believe to be a deadlocking process.  It shows it with a database id of 32767 and an object id of -710746692. I looked in sys.databases and sys.objects and didn't find anything for these. I did a search for the Database ID and believe it to be the hidden Resource Database that sql server has.  However, a google search didn't return anything meaningful for the object id.

What is Object ID -710746692?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Erik mentioned, 32767 is the resource database, and it is hidden from the `sys.databases` view, but that doesn't mean the object you're after lives *only* there - in fact most system objects are in all databases.

To determine the object, we just need to pass your `object_id` to a query against `sys.all_objects` (rather than `sys.objects`):

```
SELECT name FROM sys.all_objects 
  WHERE object_id = -710746692;
```

And the result:

```
sp_MSreplupdateschema
```

So, sounds to me like something is messed up with your replication configuration, or you're just throwing too much concurrent changes at it. If this is only happening during deployments or specific activities I would try to eliminate those as causes.

Otherwise, like Erik said, there's not much you can do about it - it's not like you can edit that stored procedure, even if you do understand why it's deadlocking, so you'll have to troubleshoot it from the feature side. You could upload the .xdl graph and someone could take a look and maybe figure out if it's deadlocking because of something else you *can* control.

Comment: thank you!  we took a look at our replication and found that we were generating a snapshot every hour, which was most likely causing the deadlocks.  we killed it (we don't need it) and will continue to monitor to see if that clears things up for us.